# how to append the second or third word of input to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am using Python

**This is the code that I have tried:**

```
PIKACHU = {}
command = input("Command: ")
if "Capture" in command:
  command = command.split(' ')
  command.append[1]
if "Query" in command:
  command = command.split(' ')

print(PIKACHU[2])
```

**Example of what I want to happen:**

```
 - Command: Capture Pikachu 6
Command: Query Pikachu
Pikachu is level 6.
Command: Query Pikachu
Pikachu is level 6.
Command: Query Eevee
You have not captured Eevee yet.
Command:
```

**Another example:**

```
- Command: Capture Eevee 4
Command: Query Eevee
Eevee is level 4.
Command: Capture Eevee 6
You are already training Eevee!
Command:
```

**Another example:**

```
- Command: Capture Froakie 12
Command: Battle Froakie
Unknown command!
Command: Feed Froakie 5
Unknown command!
Command: Query Froakie
Froakie is level 12.
```

Command:

I am very unfamiliar with dictionaries, so I am finding it difficult knowing how to append certain words from input to a dictionary with . Or if lists may be better?

Thank you in advance. I am very confused. :)

Comment: you;ve never "used" the variable `PIKACHU` after creating it, so im not sure why you are expecting it to do anything.

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the possible user entries? like are you trying to provide Pokemon names every time? please provide some examples of inputs and what you would like to do with them. I'm not fully clear about the requirement from your question.

Comment: can you provide proper code you use and any error you face then let me which version you use of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding your question properly. Based on your examples, here is what I think you are trying to do.

-If command string is inputted, store pokemon and level in dictionary

-If query string is inputted, ouput string with pokemon name and level.

Here is how you would do that:

```
Pokemon = {}
command = input("Command: ")
if "Capture" in command:
    command = command.split(' ')
    Pokemon[command[1]] = command[2]
    #stores Pokemon name as key and level as value

if "Query" in command:
     command = command.split(' ')
     if command[1] not in Pokemon: #checks if pokemon is not in dictionary
         print("You have not captured" +  command[1] + "yet.")
     else:
         print(command[1] "is level " + Pokemon[command[1]]) 
         #prints pokemon name and level, which is gotten from dictionary
```

Dictionaries act like hashmaps, with a key value pair. So here I am creating a dictionary name pokemon, and storing the name of the pokemon as the key and level as value.

With multiple pokemon of same name:

```
Pokemon = {}
command = input("Command: ")
if "Capture" in command:
    command = command.split(' ')
    if command[1] not in Pokemon:
        Pokemon[command[1]] = [command[2]] 
        #if pokemon does not exist in dict yet
        #create new list with first pokemon and store its level
    else:
        Pokemon[command[1]].append(command[2])
        #appends the list value at the pokemon name with the 
        #new pokemon's level

if "Query" in command: 
     command = command.split(' ')
     if command[1] not in Pokemon: #checks if pokemon is not in dictionary
         print("You have not captured" +  command[1] + "yet.")
     else:
         print(command[1] "is level " + Pokemon[command[1]]) 
         #will print a list of pokemon
         #Example: Eevee is level [2,3,5]
         #If you want to specify which pokemon, enter index of list in 
         #Query and get pokemon through it.
```

Comment: thank you very much for this! do you know what you would need to do to say that the pokemon is already in training, if the user querys and captures the same pokemon?

Comment: Well if you plan on having more than one pokemon, say Eevee level 6 and 2, you would want to store the value of the dictionary as a list. Check my edited example for more info!